# Algorithm For Detecting Multiple Regions In a Two Dimensional Array

Tags: algorithm

I have a two dimensional 30x30 array which represents an area. A sample area with regions illustrated the image below.(An example image). In the map there are regions are determined with borders. The regions can be different shapes. My question is there any algorithm to count the regions in this area.

[image]

Comment: The google words are "number of islands"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible algorithm

```
while ((empty = findempty))
  flodfill(empty)
  count++
```

- Find an empty square.
- Use flood fill to fill it out (or BFS).
- increase count.
- start again if more empty.